# ExpressJS, MongoDB + Socket.IO - Identify Individual User Session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io, pug

I'm using https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/tree/es6. I added Socket.IO but can't figure out a way to safely get current logged in user information . I have a button that when pressed I want to send to the server (Username, Balance, and Amount so I can update their Schema model safely ... So far i was able to so with Jade but I'm sure this is really bad .

JADE:

```
.content-r-inner.child
    .col-md-12.col-xs-12.col-lg-12.no-pad-home
    if !user
      include partials/flash
      include partials/visitorbar
    else 
      include partials/userbar
    |           
    #time.timecontainer.pulsing.pulsingbox
    |           
    .product Product: 
    |  
    input#amount(type='text')
    |           
    #slider-range-max
    |           
    #minus1.minus.unselectable -
    |           
    #plus1.plus.unselectable +
    // </div>
    .sendAmount(onclick="GetAmount()")


// inside include partials/userbar I have GetAmount Function
function GetAmount(){
socket.emit('getAmount', {
"username": "#{user.username}",
"maxBalance": "#{user.balance}",
"getAmount": document.getElementById('amount').value 
});
}
```

## {user.username} you can be seen inside  tags...

```
function GetAmount(){
  socket.emit('getAmount', {
  "username": "JohnDoe",
  "maxBalance": "3750",
  "getAmount": document.getElementById('amount').value 
  });
}
```

I'm sure there is a better more safer way of identifying which user pressed the Button... Hope someone can explain the best way I could achieve it with Socket.IO, just started using it and I find it to be a lot better than Ajax in many ways but currently lack basic understanding of it's methodology and even Mongo for that matter :))

Thank you for your help ! Kudos !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [socketio-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt) (https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt) I think it's what you're after. Basically you need authentication for the active users.

Comment: Seems very interesting, will take a closer look. It seems that approaching token based auth on top of socket.io might be better than gold old cookies :D . Thx for sharing @akazemis !!!